# How to get button to output value multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

I am playing around with a program that picks a value out of an array, but I am having trouble getting a new output after initially clicking the button. It will only allow me to get a new output when I refresh the page. How can I get a new output each time I click the button?

```js
    var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

    var concat = myArray[rand];

    function random() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (concat);
    }
```

```html
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <button onClick="random()">
    Working Random Array generator
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `rand` and `concat` variables definition inside `random()` function to get the new output on button click.

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];

function random() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  var concat = myArray[rand];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (concat);
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onClick="random()">Working Random Array generator</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example will generate a different result each time without repeating the same thing twice in succession. This ensures that you will have a new and different result with each click.

### Option 1:  Global variable

The algorithm compares the last result used and assigns it to the variable `lastUsed`. When clicked again - it is checked whether the result is different from `lastUsed` if it is the same the function **itself is called again** until it returns a different result

**Example:**

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];
var lastUsed;

function random() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

    if(myArray[rand] !==  lastUsed) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArray[rand];
        lastUsed = myArray[rand];
    } else {
        random();
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="random()">
    Working Random Array generator
</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

### Option 2: innerText

Another way to make this comparison without using a global variable is to check what the current value is in the `id="demo"` element.

**Example:**

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];

function random() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var lastUsed = x.innerText;

    if (myArray[rand] !== lastUsed) {
        x.innerHTML = myArray[rand];
        lastUsed = myArray[rand];
    } else {
        random();
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="random()">
    Working Random Array generator
</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

### Option 3: localStorage

If necessary, we must be sure that we will get a different result from the previous one, even after **reloading the entire page**. You can save the last value used in `localStorage`

**Example:**

```
<button onClick="random()">
    Working Random Array generator
</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];

    function random() {

        var lastUsed;

        var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("myRandomInfo");
        if (retrievedData) {
            var myValue = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
            var lastUsed = myValue.myRandomInfo;
        }

        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

        if (myArray[rand] !== lastUsed) {
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myArray[rand];

            var lastUsed = ({ myRandomInfo: myArray[rand] });
            localStorage.setItem("myRandomInfo", JSON.stringify(lastUsed));
        } else {
            random();
        }

    }
</script>
```